# How to parse a SQL result and convert it to Ruby hash

Tags: sql, ruby

I want to convert a SQL query result into a Ruby hash, where only two rows are shown and the first act as key and second as value. For example, if my query got this result:

`+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+--- +--------+
| 1  |    a   |
| 2  |    b   |
| 3  |    c   |
| 4  |    d   |
| 5  |    e   |
+----+--------+`

I want to manipulate this data to get a Ruby hash like this:

```
h = { '1' => 'a',
      '2' => 'b'.
      '3' => 'c',
      '4' => 'd',
      '5' => 'e' }
```

How can I get this done?

Comment: It depends which RubyGem as a DB adapter you are using..

Comment: Are you using mysql2 adapter or active record? What is your current approach?

Comment: Just running queries manually, question it's more about text parsing in Ruby than SQL adapters or ORM usage.

I guess I will take `sed` as a way to go and copy the result in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I use ruby [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) in most of my non-rails projects. It's an excellent [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) for SQL databases.

Here is a code sample using SQLite (in memory):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'sequel'

# create db in memory
DB = Sequel.sqlite

# create table
DB.create_table :items do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
end

# Create a dataset
items = DB[:items] 

# Populate the table
items.insert(:name => 'john')
items.insert(:name => 'mike')
items.insert(:name => 'nick')

puts "#{items.all}"
# => [{:id=>1, :name=>"john"}, {:id=>2, :name=>"mike"}, {:id=>3, :name=>"nick"}]

# initialize hash object
h = {}

# Create the hash in the form you want
items.all.each do |entry|
  h[entry[:id]]= entry[:name]
end 

# p the hash
p h # => {1=>"john", 2=>"mike", 3=>"nick"}
```

NOTE: Sequel is extremely powerful. There might be a method to do what you what you want directly, without passing the data through the loop. However, you'll have to [read the documentation](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/) to find out if you need to clean your code.

Hope this helps!

UPDATE: So here is the updated code after Jeremy Evan's (author of Sequel):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'sequel'

# create db in memory
DB = Sequel.sqlite

# create table
DB.create_table :items do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
end

# Create a dataset
items = DB[:items] 

# Populate the table
items.insert(:name => 'john')
items.insert(:name => 'mike')
items.insert(:name => 'nick')

# Return hash of items
p items.select_hash(:id, :name) # => {1=>"john", 2=>"mike", 3=>"nick"}
```

Comment: There is a method, `items.select_hash(:id, :name)`